# Ubuntu 17.10: Too many errors from stdin

Tags: ubuntu, runtime-error, stdin, ubuntu-17.10

I have a VM under Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm having some trouble: I'm getting the following message every time when I'm using nano / etc.:

**Too many errors from stdin**

I'd try google it, but can't find solution. Thank you

Comment: You should post this on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @AksharPatel, okey, thanks.